# I've created an empty database without any tables, and data inside

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I've got a problem with my db. There's no any tables, and data, just empty database. What should I change in code? I want to create an database, with hardcoded values, because i'd want to use them later in spinner.

```
Database class

    public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CurrencyExchange.db";
    private static final String CURRENCY_TABLE = "currency_table";



    public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+CURRENCY_TABLE+ " ( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, BGN TEXT, NZD TEXT, ILS TEXT, RUB TEXT, CAD TEXT, USD TEXT, PHP TEXT, CHF TEXT, ZAR TEXT, AUD TEXT, JPY TEXT, TRY TEXT, HKD TEXT, MYR TEXT, THB TEXT, HRK TEXT, NOK TEXT, IDR TEXT, DKK TEXT, CZK TEXT, HUF TEXT, GBP TEXT, MXN TEXT, KRW TEXT, ISK TEXT, SGD TEXT, BRL TEXT, PLN TEXT, INR TEXT, RON TEXT, CNY TEXT, SEK TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+CURRENCY_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    final String insert_data = "INSERT INTO "+CURRENCY_TABLE+ " VALUES (0,'BGN','NZD','ILS','RUB','CAD','USD','PHP','CHF','ZAR','AUD','JPY','TRY','HKD','MYR','THB','HRK','NOK','IDR','DKK','CZK','HUF','GBP','MXN','KRW','ISK','SGD','BRL','PLN','INR','RON','CNY','SEK')";
    contentValues.put(CURRENCY_TABLE, insert_data);
    return database.insert(CURRENCY_TABLE, null, contentValues) != -1;
}
```

MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Database database;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    database = new Database(this);
    database.insertData();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do (*see below for why this is probably not what you want to do*) is change the **insertData** method to be :-

```
public boolean insertData( String bgn, String nzd, String ils, String run, String cad,
                           String usd, String php, String chf, String zar, String aud, String jpy,
                           String TRY, String hkd, String myr, String thb, String hrk, String nok,
                           String idr, String dkk, String czk, String huf, String gbp, String mxn,
                           String krw, String isk, String sgd, String brl, String pln, String inr,
                           String ron, String cny, String sek){

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("BGN",bgn);
    contentValues.put("NZD",nzd);
    contentValues.put("ILS",ils);
    contentValues.put("RUB",run);
    contentValues.put("CAD",cad);
    contentValues.put("USD",usd);
    contentValues.put("PHP",php);
    contentValues.put("CHF",chf);
    contentValues.put("ZAR",zar);
    contentValues.put("AUD",aud);
    contentValues.put("JPY",jpy);
    contentValues.put("TRY",TRY);
    contentValues.put("HKD",hkd);
    contentValues.put("MYR",myr);
    contentValues.put("BGN",bgn);
    contentValues.put("THB",thb);
    contentValues.put("HRK",hrk);
    contentValues.put("NOK",nok);
    contentValues.put("IDR",idr);
    contentValues.put("DKK",dkk);
    contentValues.put("CZK",czk);
    contentValues.put("HUF",huf);
    contentValues.put("GBP",gbp);
    contentValues.put("MXN",mxn);
    contentValues.put("KRW",krw);
    contentValues.put("ISK",isk);
    contentValues.put("SGD",sgd);
    contentValues.put("BRL",brl);
    contentValues.put("PLN",pln);
    contentValues.put("INR",inr);
    contentValues.put("RON",ron);
    contentValues.put("CNY",cny);
    contentValues.put("SEK",sek);
    return database.insert(CURRENCY_TABLE, null, contentValues) != -1;
}
```

- Of course this assumes that you want to insert a value for each column *using VALUES without a comma separated list of columns inside parentheses specifies all columns*
- Note no values is given for the first column ID, this will then be auto generated as is the typical use of an ID column.

Adding this method

```
public Cursor getAllRowsFromCurrencyTable() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.query(CURRENCY_TABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

and the using the following in an Activity and running it once :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Database database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        database = new Database(this);
        // Add a row for tesing
        database.insertData("A","B","C","D",
                "E","F","G","H","I",
                "J","K","L","M","N",
                "O","P","Q","R","S",
                "T","U","V","W","X",
                "Y","Z","AA","AB","AC",
                "AD","AE","AF"
        );
        // Get all the rows (1) and dump the resultant Cursor
        Cursor csr = database.getAllRowsFromCurrencyTable();
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr.close(); // Should always close a Cursor when done with it.

    }
}
```

results in :-

```
2019-05-13 19:37:28.974 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@76cd9ae
2019-05-13 19:37:28.974 I/System.out: 0 {
2019-05-13 19:37:28.975 I/System.out:    ID=1
2019-05-13 19:37:28.975 I/System.out:    BGN=A
2019-05-13 19:37:28.975 I/System.out:    NZD=B
2019-05-13 19:37:28.975 I/System.out:    ILS=C
2019-05-13 19:37:28.975 I/System.out:    RUB=D
2019-05-13 19:37:28.975 I/System.out:    CAD=E
2019-05-13 19:37:28.975 I/System.out:    USD=F
2019-05-13 19:37:28.975 I/System.out:    PHP=G
2019-05-13 19:37:28.975 I/System.out:    CHF=H
2019-05-13 19:37:28.975 I/System.out:    ZAR=I
2019-05-13 19:37:28.975 I/System.out:    AUD=J
2019-05-13 19:37:28.975 I/System.out:    JPY=K
2019-05-13 19:37:28.976 I/System.out:    TRY=L
2019-05-13 19:37:28.976 I/System.out:    HKD=M
2019-05-13 19:37:28.976 I/System.out:    MYR=N
2019-05-13 19:37:28.976 I/System.out:    THB=O
2019-05-13 19:37:28.976 I/System.out:    HRK=P
2019-05-13 19:37:28.976 I/System.out:    NOK=Q
2019-05-13 19:37:28.976 I/System.out:    IDR=R
2019-05-13 19:37:28.976 I/System.out:    DKK=S
2019-05-13 19:37:28.976 I/System.out:    CZK=T
2019-05-13 19:37:28.976 I/System.out:    HUF=U
2019-05-13 19:37:28.976 I/System.out:    GBP=V
2019-05-13 19:37:28.977 I/System.out:    MXN=W
2019-05-13 19:37:28.977 I/System.out:    KRW=X
2019-05-13 19:37:28.977 I/System.out:    ISK=Y
2019-05-13 19:37:28.977 I/System.out:    SGD=Z
2019-05-13 19:37:28.977 I/System.out:    BRL=AA
2019-05-13 19:37:28.977 I/System.out:    PLN=AB
2019-05-13 19:37:28.977 I/System.out:    INR=AC
2019-05-13 19:37:28.977 I/System.out:    RON=AD
2019-05-13 19:37:28.977 I/System.out:    CNY=AE
2019-05-13 19:37:28.977 I/System.out:    SEK=AF
2019-05-13 19:37:28.977 I/System.out: }
2019-05-13 19:37:28.977 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

- Note ID= 1 the autogenerated ID next would likely be 2, then 3 etc (no guarantee that numbers will be sequenced, but quite likely).

---

## However

As you say

> I want to create an database, with hardcoded values, because i'd want
>   to use them later in spinner.

Then you probably do not want to use columns for the currency codes but rather have x rows 1 per currency.

So perhaps consider this working example, with a Spinner listing the currency codes and issuing a Toast when you select a different code :-

The modified **Database.java**

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CurrencyExchange.db";
    public static final String CURRENCY_TABLE = "currency_table";
    public static final String CURRENCY_ID_COLUMN = BaseColumns._ID; // Allows Spinner/ListView with Cursor Adapter
    public static final String CURRENCY_CODE_COLUMN = "currency_code";

    // The Currency Codes
    public static final String[] currency_codes = new String[]{
            "BGN", "NZD", "ILS", "RUB", "CAD", "USD", "PHP", "CHF",
            "ZAR", "AUD", "JPY", "TRY", "HKD", "MYR", "THB", "HRK",
            "NOK", "IDR", "DKK", "CZK", "HUF", "GBP", "MXN", "KRW",
            "ISK ", "SGD", "BRL", "PLN", "INR", "RON", "CNY", "SEK"
    };

    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2); // Version changed so will drop old table and recreate new
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        /* OLD
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + CURRENCY_TABLE + " ( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "BGN TEXT, NZD TEXT, ILS TEXT, RUB TEXT, CAD TEXT, USD TEXT, PHP TEXT, CHF TEXT, " +
                "ZAR TEXT, AUD TEXT, JPY TEXT, TRY TEXT, HKD TEXT, MYR TEXT, THB TEXT, HRK TEXT, " +
                "NOK TEXT, IDR TEXT, DKK TEXT, CZK TEXT, HUF TEXT, GBP TEXT, MXN TEXT, KRW TEXT, " +
                "ISK TEXT, SGD TEXT, BRL TEXT, PLN TEXT, INR TEXT, RON TEXT, CNY TEXT, SEK TEXT)");
        */
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + CURRENCY_TABLE + "(" +
                CURRENCY_ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + // NO NEED FOR AUTOINCREMENT (it's inefficient)
                CURRENCY_CODE_COLUMN + " TEXT UNIQUE " + // UNIQUE means will not add duplicates
                ")");
        addAllCurrencyCodes(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CURRENCY_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    private void addAllCurrencyCodes(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        if (database == null) {
            database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        database.beginTransaction();
        for (String currency_code: currency_codes) {
            addCurrencyCode(currency_code,database);
        }
        database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        database.endTransaction();
    }

    public void addCurrencyCode(String code, SQLiteDatabase database) {

        if (database == null) {
            database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(CURRENCY_CODE_COLUMN,code);
        database.insert(CURRENCY_TABLE,null,contentValues);
    }

    public Cursor getAllRowsFromCurrencyTable() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.query(CURRENCY_TABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

The activity's layout (i.e. Spinner Added) **activity_main.xml** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/currrency_code_selector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Spinner>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally the changed activity **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Database database;
    Spinner currency_code_selector;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
    Cursor csr;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        currency_code_selector = this.findViewById(R.id.currrency_code_selector);

        database = new Database(this);
        // For testing only
        csr = database.getAllRowsFromCurrencyTable();
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        manageCurrencyCodeSpinner();
    }

    private void manageCurrencyCodeSpinner() {
        csr = database.getAllRowsFromCurrencyTable();
        if (mSCA == null) {
            mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this, // The context
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, // The layout (stock layout used)
                    csr, // The Cursor for the Spinner
                    new String[]{Database.CURRENCY_CODE_COLUMN}, // The columns holding the data
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, // The View into which the data is placed
                    0 // 0 is fine
            );
            currency_code_selector.setAdapter(mSCA); // Tie the adapter to the Spinner
            // Setup selection handling
            currency_code_selector.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if (view == null) return;
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                            "You have just selected the currency code " +
                                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(Database.CURRENCY_CODE_COLUMN)) +
                                    ". The ID is " + String.valueOf(id),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        } else {
            mSCA.swapCursor(csr); // if spinner already setup refresh the contents
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        csr.close(); //<<<<<<<<<< close the cursor when done with it
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        manageCurrencyCodeSpinner(); // refresh the Spinner as data may have changed
    }
}
```

The Result  :-

[image]

- obviously you'd enhance the appearance, this is just a demo
- You just have to take my word for it that the Toast works (could capture it)
- **Note** to deploy this change you should do one one of the following :-

  - uninstall the App
  - delete the App's data
  - increase the version number i.e. change `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);` to `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);`

Comment: I'm really surprised, i'd want to thank you a lot. But if my code would run in first time, it would be boring... :) I've got an issue, with spinner, it doesn't show anything. I'll edit my question with updated code

Comment: @Szal21, it would be better if you asked that as another question. One suggestion, create another project and copy the code as is. If that works (should do unless I made an error) then slowly change the original accordingly. The spinner aspect is quite some way past the original question and could be confusing to others.

Comment: Ok then, I'll try to fix it on my own.

Comment: @Szal21 you did do one of the three options as per the note at the end (uninstall the App, delete the App's data or increase the version number).

Comment: It's working now, but i've faced another problem. I don't have mind for it for today :)

Comment: @Szal21 the golden rule to remember that unlike an activity where onCreate always appears to run, the **onCreate** method in the Database Helper only ever runs once, after running the database the exists (actually it is created and then onCreate is called).  As I said subsequent problems should really be new questions. It's not that I or somebody doesn't want to help, it's how StackOverflow is meant to work.

Comment: There's no problem about it, just didn't know about  that. I will remember that. Thank you again for help, I'm really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you use `ContentValues`

With the `insert_data` variable you made, you can use `db.execSQL()` again

```
db.execSQL(insert_data);
```

If you want to use `ContentValues` and `database.insert()` you have to use it like that:

```
ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
values.put(COLUMN1_NAME, value1);
values.put(COLUMN2_NAME, value2);
values.put(COLUMN3_NAME, value3);
//for each column of your table

return database.insert(CURRENCY_TABLE, null, values) != -1;
```